# how to interacts with database in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i installed rails on ruby and i have mysql as a database installed now how i interacts with datbase uisng rails ,will i have to install mysql gems for ruby or what  first step i have to do.
in tutorials its written like that
creates your rails applicationl like

rails appname

cd to appname

rails appname -d mysql

will it be enough to start interaction with mysql database without installing mysql gems??

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes.  If you installed rails, you most likely already have the mysql gem installed.  If for some reason you don't, you can install it with `gem install mysql`.

Comment: thanks..
means without installing mysql gem i can't interact with data base

Comment: nd one more thing whats mysql gem will do ,it it there to make bridge between rails and mysql database??

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It is equivalent to C's MySQL API (because it pretty much IS that API with some Ruby bindings).  http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/

Comment: You will have to modify config/database.yml if your mysql is password protected or you are not going to run as root.
Then run 'rake db:create' to create the database.